# How should we design/write a connection pool

Tags: algorithm, oop, data-structures

I came across with this interview question, and I am curious if my idea is right. How should we design/write a connection pool (i.e, a class that returns connections to the user, and if the user is done, returns them back to the pool).
My idea is that to create the pool in Singleton pattern, and has an inner class called Connection. The pool would hold an array of connections object, and which connection object has a boolean field indicates if the connection is available (being used or not), and register the pool with the connection object. When the connection is called close() by user, connection would notify the pool to update, probably like availableConnection, and change isAvaiable to true in the connection.

Is there any more things that I should add to it? Am I missing something? It sounds like Object Pool Pattern might be useful here, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'd say best start coding the mock-up. Then you'll see how it comes together. And yes, Object Pool pattern is spot-on here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping a boolean flag, just maintain two lists, one for maintaining the used objects, and the other for the available objects. This makes searching easier when the count of used objects is low.

However the Object Pool Pattern is not preferred in the programming languages which use garbage collectors. 
(Most garbage collectors scan "live" object references, and not the memory that these objects use for their content. This means that any number of "dead" objects without references can be discarded with little cost. In contrast, keeping a large number of "live" but unused objects increases the duration of garbage collection.)